# Silverlight Listbox selectable ItemTemplate

Tags: silverlight, listbox, datatemplate

I have a Usercontrol that contains a ListBox (lstClients) and a ComboBox

The ListBox has 2 DataTemplates setup as Resources called "LowDetailTemplate" and "HighDetailTemplate"

I need to be able to switch between the 2 DataTemplates when I change the value in a ComboBox from "Low" to "High" and vice versa. In the SelectionChanged event of the ComboBox I'm guessing I need to change the ItemTemplate of the ListBox but I'm struggling with the code to assign the DataTemplate in code behind. My latest attempt is shown below but it fails at runtime.

```
lstClients.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["LowDetailTemplate"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to define both of the views inside the same data template and then switch which is visible by use of a simple variable. Then your combo box change would just update that simple variable and so cause the view shown for each template instance to change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Phil, maybe I'm approaching this from the wrong direction. It seemed an obvious use of DataTemplates to be able to switch them. I'm assuming this isn't the case. I've tried using the VisualStateManager too but it doesn't seem to play nicely with DataTemplates.